# Deleting files based on filename similarity

Tags: python, csv

I have a few, quite large, folders containing many csv files following the naming convention shown below:

GAbc_Pt0_20210605_142451

Edit: Pt values can range from 0-4, and date values can range quite a bit.

I'm trying to delete files that share the same 'Pt' value and the same '20210X0X' value while keeping the first instance.

How can I go about accomplishing this?

Edit: here's what I currently have

```
i = 0
pDataLoc = []
for root, subdirectories, files in os.walk(filePath):
    for subdirectory in subdirectories:
        if subdirectory == 'ProcessedData':
            pDataLoc.append(os.path.join(root, subdirectory))
            i+=1

for directory in pDataLoc:
    fileList = os.listdir(directory)

    #splits and collects meta data from file names
    fileNameMetaData = [data for file in os.listdir(directory) for data 
    in re.split("_", file)]

    #Pt 
    srch = 'Pt'
    r = re.compile(fr'(?<=){srch}(?=)')
    site = list(filter(r.findall, fileNameMetaData))

    #date
    srch = '2021'
    r = re.compile(fr'(?<=){srch}(?=)')
    date = list(filter(r.findall, fileNameMetaData))
```

note: the data files are stored in nested folders

I'm trying to compile the relevant information into a list to facilitate some sort of simultaneous 'if ==' type logic to identify the files to be deleted, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to employ this - let alone how to employ this without losing the first instance found.

Not sure if this is the best approach, so any criticism would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the `142451` part of `GAbc_Pt0_20210605_142451.csv` is 14:24:51 as hours:minutes:seconds in a 24-hour format, and "first instance" you want to keep is the one which is the earliest in time. And I hope that morning hours are `_072451` and not `_72451`.

If that's right, your filenames could be sorted alphabetically, and split along the last `_`, comparing the first half with the previous one (if it's a match, we kept an instance already, if they don't match, a new block has just started and this is the instance to be kept):

```
import os

files = os.listdir()
files.sort()
seen = ''
for file in files:
  if file.endswith(".csv"):
    firsthalf = file[:file.rfind('_')]
    if seen == firsthalf:
      os.remove(file)
    else:
      seen = firsthalf
```

The code does a single minimal check only, it doesn't touch anything what is not a `.csv` file.

Comment: So this solution almost works, but there's one slight problem - not with your solution, but my data set. It's finding all the data files with the criteria 'ends with csv', but then returns a 'FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'GAbc_Pt0_20210606_140011.csv''. The names when shown in my explorer are missing the '.csv', so could that be causing this issue?

Comment: Explorer hides extensions as its factory setting and displays some "Type" column instead (in list views). The ’if file.endswith('.csv')` check would not pass if they weren't .csv files. Despite the wording of the message, I would rather think that the file is there (as it comes from a file listing...), just it can't be deleted. There can be a number of reasons, like file is marked read-only, it is opened by another process, or even the user has no rights do write/delete anything in that directory.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it by using os.path.join to generate the 'file' portion. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

```
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('path/to/my/folder'):
    for file in files:
        if file.startswith('GAbc_Pt0_20210605'):
            to_delete = os.path.join(root, file)
            print('Deleting: {}'.format(to_delete)
            os.remove(to_delete)
```

By doing this you will look recursively into the folder and search for a file that
start with `GAbc_Pt0_20210605` (Same Pt0 and same date). Change this for another pt0 or another date and you should be good

Edit:

On your second comment you can do:

```
import re
import os

my_list = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('my_dir'):
    for file in files:
        match = re.search(r'GAbc_(Pt[0-4])_(\d{8})_.*', file)
        if match:
             pt_value = match.group(1)
             date = match.group(2)
             path_to_file = os.path.join(root, file)
             my_list.append((pt_value, date, path_to_file))
```

Then you can filter the list and delete the files you want

Comment: I'm afraid that there are too many combinations of potential Pt and date values for this to work for me. I suppose the real question I'm asking would be something like "how do I compare just portions of the filenames in a directory, and then delete the files that have matching values"? - I'll make an edit of that, apologies for any confusion on that.

Comment: My current approach is to append all the filenames into a list, and place the pt and date values in separate lists. As they should all have the same length, I figured trying to loop through all 3 checking for equivalency, and popping values where it's found,  would work however I'm having trouble thinking of an effective way to implement that.

Comment: @RichardKim, update your question for me to answer correctly

Comment: The question has been updated with everything I have right now

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this string 'Pt0_20210605' of your file name is always in [5:17] you can solve this problem with logic like this:

```
import os

f=[]
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('path/to/my/folder'):
    for file in files:
        if file[5:17] in f:
            to_delete=os.path.join(root,file)
            os.remove(to_delete)        
        else:
            f.append(file[5:17])
```